# pgfplots: compute axis cs point with pgfmath

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to construct a plot using pgfplots in which I perform `\draw` commands using `axis cs`. Additionally, the coordinates of `axis cs` are assigned to the result of a math expression using an iterator generated with a `foreach` loop. Here's the code I've got:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  title=Sinusoid Sampled Values (1 Period),
  xlabel={$t$},
  ylabel={$A$},
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=left,
  xmin=0, xmax=2*pi,
  ymin=-1, ymax=1,
]
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,15} {
    \draw (axis cs:\pgfmathparse{2*pi*\x/16}\pgfmathresult,0)
      -- (axis cs:\pgfmathparse{2*pi*\x/16}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{sin(2*pi*\x/16)}\pgfmathresult)
      circle[radius=2];
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this fails I'm unsure which part of the process is creating the issue. I suspect it's `pgfmathparse`, but maybe it's the loop? How can I achieve the desired result here? Let me know if you need any further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pgfplots-internal commands to achieve (probably) the same:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Sinusoid Sampled Values (1 Period),
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$A$},
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=left,
        xmin=0, xmax=2*pi,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    ]

    \addplot[ycomb, domain=0:15, samples=16, mark=*] (2*pi*x/16, {sin(2*pi*x/16 r)});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Note: as pgf expects degree in trigonometric functions, I added the `r` to convert it to radians.
[image]

Another (even easier) solution:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Sinusoid Sampled Values (1 Period),
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$A$},
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=left,
        xmin=0, xmax=2*pi,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        xtick={0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2, 2*pi},
        xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,  $\pi$, $\frac{3}{2}\pi$, $2\pi$}
    ]

    \addplot expression[ycomb, domain=0:{30/16*pi}, samples=16, mark=o] {sin(\x r)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]